# How to implement a kernel of size 1 in a Gaussian filter in opencv?

Tags: python, opencv, gaussianblur

I'm trying to create a 1 pixel kernel:

```
x = cv2.getGaussianKernel(1, 2)
```

And I use it in a gaussian filter:

```
blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(img, x, 0)
```

As a result, an error occurs:

```
SystemError: new style getargs format but argument is not a tuple
```

How to fix this error?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot pass a kernel to the GaussianBlur function. You must pass the kernel size.

So x should be a tuple like (5,5) or (3,3) etc

Also the kernel size values should be Odd and positive and can differ. You cannot use the size(1,2) since 2 is even.

If you want to see the Gaussian kernel use this:

```
cv2.getGaussianKernel(ksize, sigma[, ktype])
```

EX:

```
kernel = cv2.getGaussianKernel(ksize=(1,1),sigma=2)
```

If you want to blur the image using the kernel then use this:

```
cv2.GaussianBlur(src, ksize, sigmaX[, dst[, sigmaY[, borderType]]])
```

EX:

```
cv2.GaussianBlur(src, ksize=(1,1))
```

check [this](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html#void%20GaussianBlur(InputArray%20src,%20OutputArray%20dst,%20Size%20ksize,%20double%20sigmaX,%20double%20sigmaY,%20int%20borderType))

Comment: Note from the help: `possible future modifications of all this semantics, it is recommended to specify all of ksize, sigmaX, and sigmaY.`

Comment: In this case 2 is sigma. Documentation: Python: cv2.getGaussianKernel(ksize, sigma[, ktype]) → retval

Comment: Then you must pass the ksize and sigma to gaussianBlur itself. cv2.GaussianBlur(src, ksize, sigmaX[, dst[, sigmaY[, borderType]]])